# NHibernate: How to set DynamicUpdate on all Entities?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How can I set DynamicUpdate and DynamicInsert on all my entities?

It works perfectly when I put it together with my mapping code, but I would like to specify it only once for my entire project.

I could not find an option when creating the Session or in the Configuration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use fluent nhibernate so I would change them like this:

```
var fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure())
      .Mappings(m =>
          m.FluentMappings
          .AddFromAssemblyOf<OrderMap>()
          .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<PascalCaseColumnNameConvention>())
          .ProxyFactoryFactory("NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate");

var config = fluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration();

foreach(PersistentClass persistentClass in config.ClassMappings)
{
    persistentClass.DynamicUpdate = true;
}

var sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: You read my mind, I am using fluent nHibernate as well, so this works perfectly.

Comment: This approach will also work with plain vanilla NHibernate, since it's modifying the `Configuration`.  Another more Fluent-NHibernate-esque option would be to create an IClassConvention.

Answer (score 3):

When using mapping-by-code its as simple as this:-

```
var mapper = new ModelMapper();

mapper.BeforeMapClass += (mi, t, map) =>
    {
        map.DynamicUpdate(true);
        map.DynamicInsert(true);
    };

...
```

Just make sure you remove it from ALL your class by class mappings as they will override this convention.

Just to complete if you do want to override any class definitions then you can also use

```
mapper.AfterMapClass += (mi, t, map) => { ... }
```

Comment: This works, but I am using Fluent NHibertnate, so @Cole-w answers fits a bit better.

Comment: No worries, have added the tag `Fluent-NHibernate` to your original post.